# How to add icon or watermark image to immediately after taking screenshot in android with support multiple screen sizes

Tags: java, android

**Please re-read my question before a vote, I want to add an icon or png image to a screenshot image immediately after taking**

**I don't know is it a good approach or not, but I tried this**

```
private static Bitmap addWaterMark(Bitmap src, Context context, String waterMarkImage) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    Log.d(TAG, "Width X Height " + width + " X " + height);

    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);
    int maxX = point.x;
    int maxY = point.y;
    point.set(maxX, maxY);

    int maxWidth = (70 * width) / 100;
    int maxHeight = (80 * height) / 100;
    Log.d(TAG, "maxWidth X maxHeight " + maxWidth + " X " + maxHeight);

    Bitmap waterMark = null;
    if (waterMarkImage != null) {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(waterMarkImage, 0);
        waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
        waterMark = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(waterMark, 250, 250, true);
    } else {
        waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.sharelogo1);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, maxWidth, maxHeight, null);

    return result;
}
```

**and it's working fine but watermark image size and position is not working as I want** (not supporting all screen sizes or resolutions)

Comment: `not working as I want`-> How exactly the output differs?

Comment: I want to add an icon on the bottom right corner of the device, but it's Overlapping with content in some devices and icon size and position is changing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet change

```
waterMark = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(waterMark, 250, 250, true);
```

by

```
waterMark = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(waterMark, getpixels(250), getpixels(250), true);
```

And add below method in to convert dp to pixel

```
private float getpixels(float dipValue) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will get back to you once I check with multiple devices and versions.